# MYSQL Select weekly and monthly from database

Tags: mysql, database

Hi I need help for my problem.

I want to produce monthly and weekly reports.

First of all I already created a database named `calendar_table` wherein it contains all the date form 2010 to 2040

To visualize the problem more :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE(calendar_table.c_date),'%d %b %Y') AS DATE, IFNULL(SUM(buyers_table.sales_total),0) AS total_sales FROM buyers_table RIGHT JOIN calendar_table ON (DATE(buyers_table.buyer_date) = calendar_table.c_date) WHERE (calendar_table.c_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND NOW()) GROUP BY calendar_table.c_date
```

The current output is:

```
DATE            total_sales
23 Nov 2016     0
24 Nov 2016     0
25 Nov 2016     0
26 Nov 2016     4500
27 Nov 2016     5800
28 Nov 2016     0
29 Nov 2016     3500
```

So it producing a daily output of a week instead of weekly .

My desire output should be like this:

```
DATE            total_sales
17 Oct 2016     0
24 Oct 2016     0
31 Oct 2016     0
07 Nov 2016     4500
14 Nov 2016     5800
21 Nov 2016     0
28 Nov 2016     3500
```

Of course the logic here is the same with monthly

Hope you help me I'm a little bit confuse :)

Thanks

Comment: Generally, issues of data display (including missing data) are best resolved in application level code (e.g. a bit of PHP)

Answer (score 2):

If  week number  is enough you can use week

You have asimmetric between select and group by  (DATE_FORMAT(DATE(calendar_table.c_date),'%d %b %Y') is a day  .. you more tha a result in a ween)
try

```
  SELECT date_add('2016-01-01', INTERVAL  week('calendar_table.c_date')-1 WEEK) AS DATE, 
  IFNULL(SUM(buyers_table.sales_total),0) AS total_sales 
  FROM buyers_table RIGHT JOIN calendar_table ON (DATE(buyers_table.buyer_date) = calendar_table.c_date) 
  WHERE (calendar_table.c_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 WEEK) AND NOW()) 
  GROUP BY week('calendar_table.c_date')-1
```

and  month for month

```
  SELECT date_add('2016-01-01', INTERVAL  month('calendar_table.c_date')-1 month) AS DATE, 
  IFNULL(SUM(buyers_table.sales_total),0) AS total_sales 
  FROM buyers_table RIGHT JOIN calendar_table ON (DATE(buyers_table.buyer_date) = calendar_table.c_date) 
  WHERE (calendar_table.c_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 WEEK) AND NOW()) 
  GROUP BY month('calendar_table.c_date')-1
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting on my problem but unfortunately your answer didn't give my desire output. The output of your solution gave me Null on week and sum of all sales from the given week . Same with month :)

Comment: I tried it but still doesnt giving my desire output
I tried this : 
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE(calendar_table.c_date),'%d %b %Y') AS DATE, IFNULL(SUM(buyers_table.sales_total),0) AS total_sales FROM buyers_table RIGHT JOIN calendar_table ON (DATE(buyers_table.buyer_date) = calendar_table.c_date) WHERE (calendar_table.c_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 WEEK) AND NOW()) GROUP BY WEEK(calendar_table.c_date)

Comment: @MaryJhealynVillena   in the query in your comment You have asimmetric values between select and group by  (DATE_FORMAT(DATE(calendar_table.c_date),'%d %b %Y') is a day  .. give more then a result in a week) .. i have update the asnwer  .. let me know